# Group nested dictionary by common nested value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested dictionary :

```py
test_dict = {'crate_1' : { 'count' : 24, 'fruit' : "orange"},
             'crate_2' : {'count' : 54, 'fruit' : "apple"}, 
             'crate_3' : { 'count' : 3, 'fruit' : "mango"},
             'crate_4' : { 'count' : 2, 'fruit' : "peach"},
             'crate_5' : { 'count' : 7, 'fruit' : "mango"},
             'crate_6' : { 'count' : 1, 'fruit' : "apple"},
             'crate_7' : { 'count' : 14, 'fruit' : "orange"},
             'crate_8' : { 'count' : 7, 'fruit' : "peach"},
             'crate_9' : { 'count' : 18, 'fruit' : "mango"}
}
```

What I would like to achieve is a grouped dictionary with common nested values :

```py
sorted_test_dict = {
             'crate_1' : { 'count' : 24, 'fruit' : "orange"},
             'crate_7' : { 'count' : 14, 'fruit' : "orange"}
             'crate_2' : {'count' : 54, 'fruit' : "apple"},
             'crate_6' : { 'count' : 1, 'fruit' : "apple"}, 
             'crate_3' : { 'count' : 3, 'fruit' : "mango"},
             'crate_5' : { 'count' : 7, 'fruit' : "mango"},
             'crate_9' : { 'count' : 18, 'fruit' : "mango"},
             'crate_4' : { 'count' : 2, 'fruit' : "peach"},
             'crate_8' : { 'count' : 7, 'fruit' : "peach"}
}
```

Comment: I looked at it many times but your `sorted_test_dict` doesn't look sorted to me.

Comment: in which way is this sorted?  Did you mean "grouped" instead?

Comment: It's grouped by fruit, but there's no actual question here ... presumably it's "what is the code to ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom `key` that sorts by the value corresponding to the `'fruit'` key.

```
>>> dict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['fruit']))
{'crate_2': {'count': 54, 'fruit': 'apple'},
 'crate_6': {'count': 1, 'fruit': 'apple'},
 'crate_3': {'count': 3, 'fruit': 'mango'},
 'crate_5': {'count': 7, 'fruit': 'mango'},
 'crate_9': {'count': 18, 'fruit': 'mango'},
 'crate_1': {'count': 24, 'fruit': 'orange'},
 'crate_7': {'count': 14, 'fruit': 'orange'},
 'crate_4': {'count': 2, 'fruit': 'peach'},
 'crate_8': {'count': 7, 'fruit': 'peach'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking carefully at the example, it seems that the OP wants to keep the original `dict` ordering, but bring together all entries that have the same `'fruit'` so that they are consecutive in the result `dict`. That can be done relatively simply with a `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in test_dict.items():
    d[v['fruit']].append((k, v))
sorted_test_dict = dict([e for lst in d.values() for e in lst])
```

Outcome:

```py
>>> sorted_test_dict
{'crate_1': {'count': 24, 'fruit': 'orange'},
 'crate_7': {'count': 14, 'fruit': 'orange'},
 'crate_2': {'count': 54, 'fruit': 'apple'},
 'crate_6': {'count': 1, 'fruit': 'apple'},
 'crate_3': {'count': 3, 'fruit': 'mango'},
 'crate_5': {'count': 7, 'fruit': 'mango'},
 'crate_9': {'count': 18, 'fruit': 'mango'},
 'crate_4': {'count': 2, 'fruit': 'peach'},
 'crate_8': {'count': 7, 'fruit': 'peach'}}
```

If, however, you don't care about the original ordering, then a simple sort is fine, as others have indicated, and you can do:

```py
sorted_test_dict = dict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['fruit']))
```

Answer (score -1):

With `t` your dict:

```
print(dict(sorted(t.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['fruit'])))
```